# jQuery/AJAX Solution to check if folder exists in a network share

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently developing an internal website to provide automated account maintenance functions to end users. Part of the site is an admin portal that our L1 and L2 technicians use to provide more advanced services. I need that part of the site to see if the Powershell scripts it leverages has created a new folder yet. That folder exists on a NetAPP fileshare.

The site is coded in PHP using jQuery and AJAX scripts for file checks, etc. Most of the file checking happens in the root directory of the website, so it's easy to handle using AJAX. What I'm looking for is how to check the fileshare similar to this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(checkPRT, 5000);
function checkPRT(){
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      url: \\FILESHARE\folder\path\,
      success: function(data) {
        //alert('success!');
        window.location.href = "complete.php";
      }, error: function (data) {
        alert('failed');
      }
});
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Based on my research and what I've read on other questions related to this, AJAX can't check file locations only other URLs (with the allowglobal setting set to true). I'm still relatively new to jQuery, JavaScript, and AJAX so forgive me if I'm asking a dumb question: What is the best way to do this? I'm not limited on what languages I can use, but I'd like to keep it in the PHP/JavaScript family if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @R3tep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send an AJAX request to a PHP file where you can check whether the folder exist or not.

jQuery code:

```
function checkPRT(){
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      url: 'check_file.php',
      data: {folder_path: '\\FILESHARE\folder\path\'},
      success: function(data) {
        //alert('success!');
        if(data=='true'){ 
        window.location.href = "complete.php";
        }
      }, error: function (data) {
        alert('failed');
      }
});
}
```

PHP Code => check_file.php  :

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['folder_path']) && !empty($_GET['folder_path'])){
  if(file_exists($_GET['folder_path']){
     echo 'true';
  }else{
     echo 'false';
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: Shah, I think this is exactly what I need but I'm curious on something: I see $_GET['path'] referenced on the PHP page, but I don't see it set anywhere. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: sorry it is "folder_path". you need to pass folder path from jQuery.

Comment: and it will be bitter if you use POST method instead of GET.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I'm curious though, why are you checking isset and !empty? Is that because it's getting passed from the AJAX request and handled differently? Because if isset is 'true' then !empty would be 'false' and vice versa, right? Sorry if I'm missing something here, just trying to make sure I understand :) Also: I'll update to POST. Thanks :)

Comment: if `isset` is `true` then `!empty` can be both `false` or `true`. it's mean that check the folder if some provide none empty path via GET request.

Comment: I got it now. Because `$_GET['folder_path']` could be set to an empty value. Makes sense. Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: If you think the answer is useful then press the up button.

Comment: Not enough rep yet :) As soon as I have it, I will. Thank you, Shah!